# Convert list of matrices into a single summary data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, list, matrix

I have a list of matrices.

```
# Sample data
m1 <- matrix(c(5, 2, 8, 3, 10, 3), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(c("Mean", "SD"), c("Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas")))
m2 <- matrix(c(4, 1, 7, 2, 9, 2), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(c("Mean", "SD"), c("Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas")))
m3 <- matrix(c(6, 3, 9, 4, 11, 4), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(c("Mean", "SD"), c("Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas")))

# Create a list of data frames
matrix_list <- list(m1 = m1, m2 = m2, m3 = m3)
```

I want to combine the matrices in the list to make a summary data frame  with the following structure.

```
    Apples_Mean Apples_SD Oranges_Mean Oranges_SD Bananas_Mean Bananas_SD
m1            5         2            8          3           10          3
m2            4         1            7          2            9          2
m3            6         3            9          4           11          4
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With base R, you can use `xtabs` + `Map` + `as.data.frame` like below

```
xtabs(
    Freq ~ m + paste0(Var2, "_", Var1),
    do.call(
        rbind,
        Map(
            \(x, y) cbind(
                m = x,
                as.data.frame.table(y)
            ),
            names(matrix_list),
            matrix_list
        )
    )
)
```

which gives

```
    paste0(Var2, "_", Var1)
m    Apples_Mean Apples_SD Bananas_Mean Bananas_SD Oranges_Mean Oranges_SD
  m1           5         2           10          3            8          3
  m2           4         1            9          2            7          2
  m3           6         3           11          4            9          4
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution. As a follow up, I am trying to use this code in a shiny application and I am getting the following error. Warning: Error in eval: object 'Freq' not found. Any idea why that might have popped up?

Comment: @ZT_Geo `Freq` is from `as.data.frame.table`. I didn't use `shiny` before, I have no clue why you have that error.

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Set `dn` to the common dimnames of the matrices and then use that to define the required output column names `cn`.  Finally use `sapply` to create the result setting the names.

```
dn <- dimnames(matrix_list[[1]])
cn <- with(expand.grid(dn), paste(Var2, Var1, sep = "_"))
t(sapply(matrix_list, setNames, cn))
```

giving

```
   Apples_Mean Apples_SD Oranges_Mean Oranges_SD Bananas_Mean Bananas_SD
m1           5         2            8          3           10          3
m2           4         1            7          2            9          2
m3           6         3            9          4           11          4
```

This can alternately be written as the following where to_flat takes a matrix and flattens it out into a named vector that can be used as a row of the result.

```
to_flat <- function(x) 
  setNames(c(x), apply(expand.grid(dimnames(x)), 1, paste, collapse = "_"))
t(sapply(matrix_list, to_flat))
```

**2)** Another possibility is to use the listcompr package which provides Python-like list comprehensions.  Using dn from above the first argument of each gen_named_* function is the name to use, the second is the value and the remaining are the indexes over which to iterate.  The result is the same as above.

```
library(listcompr)

gen.named.matrix("{k}", 
  gen.named.vector("{j}_{i}", matrix_list[[k]][i, j], i = dn[[1]], j = dn[[2]]),
  k = names(matrix_list))
```